# Can I connect my guitar amp headphone out directly to laptop?

Tags: guitar, recording, homerecording

Well, I want to record myself playing guitar but I dont have any kind of audio interface ,So I came up with this is idea Can I connect my guitar amp heaphone out directly into laptop aux port? Would it harm my laptop? p.s.My amp model is Lirevo Token 10[image: Lirevo Token 10 , 10 Watt]

Answer (score 4):

It's generally OK to send a headphone output to a line-level input.  You may need to adjust the headphone volume to a suitable level to get a clear low noise but un-distorted signal.

A headphone output is generally much too high for a microphone input.  It *probably* won't damage it, but the sound will be too loud and distorted.

Comment: Plus the wire from the amp to the laptop is not balanced (shielded) and you'll hear extra noise on the line.